# Get static IP address for Heroku app

Tags: heroku, dns, hosting, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-cli

I want to make a domain point to my Heroku app, so I am trying to create an A record that targets `myapp.herokuapp.com`.

The problem is that the domain provider requires an IP address, and I cannot find any IP address for my Heroku app. I guess it might be something about Heroku only having dynamic IP addresses (and thus no static IP addresses).

How can I fix this problem? Can I make Heroku use static IP addresses?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. Maybe [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com) is a better place to ask.

Comment: just use `CNAME` record